# How to throttle number of Tasks created?

Tags: c#, asp.net, task-parallel-library, threadpool, odp.net

I'm using ODP.NET, which doesn't provide any asych methods like the SQL driver does or other Oracle drivers.

I have lots of slow queries, sometimes I need to call several of them on a single MVC controller call. So I'm trying to wrap them in Task calls. So I'm thinking of using this pattern:

(This is somewhat contrived example I wouldn't call the same query 10 times for real, it would be some heterogeneous workload)

```
List<Task<DbDataReader>> list = new List<Task<DbDataReader>>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ERROR_LOG_PKG_DR package = new ERROR_LOG_PKG_DR();
    //Could be a bunch of different queries.
    //Returns a task that has the longrunningtask property set, so it's on it's own thread
    list.Add(package.QUERY_ALL_ASYNC());
}

Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
```

And here is the task:

```
public Task<DbDataReader> QUERY_ALL_ASYNC()
{
    CancellationToken ct = new CancellationToken();
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(_ =>
                                     {               
                                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InTask: Thread: " +
                                                                            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InTask: Is Background: " +
                                                                            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
                                         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("InTask: Is ThreadPool: " +
                                                          Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
                                         return QUERY_ALL<DbDataReader>();
                                     }, null, ct,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

This fires up 10 threads. What if I wanted some thread pool like behavior-- ie. only about 4 concurrent threads at a time-- re-use threads, etc, but I want it outside of the ASP.NET thread pool (which is being used to service requests)

How do I do that?

Comment: The feasibility of any parallel code in ASP.NET really depends on how many concurrent client side requests you may have. Theoretically, acquiring 4 more threads per request would make the server scale 4 times worse. Under the low load, you may see an improvement in the response delivery. Under the high load, it will get even worse than if you didn't use extra threads at all.

Comment: It's an internal line of business application with peak concurrent users of probably about 10 or 20 in the same 20 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy to sacrifice your web app scalability, you could use `SemaphoreSlim` to throttle the number of parallel tasks:

```
const int MAX_PARALLEL_TASKS = 4;

DbDataReader GetData(CancellationToken token)
{
    DbDataReader reader = ... // execute the synchronous DB API
    return reader;
}

// this can be called form an async controller method
async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    // list of synchronous methods or lambdas to offload to thread pool
    var funcs = new Func<CancellationToken, DbDataReader>[] { 
        GetData, GetData2, ...  };

    Task<DbDataReader>[] tasks;

    using (var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MAX_PARALLEL_TASKS))
    {
        tasks = funcs.Select(async(func) => 
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                return await Task.Run(() => func(token));
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }).ToArray();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    // process the results, e.g: tasks[0].Result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need - [(msdn) How to: Create a Task Scheduler That Limits Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Shortly put idea is to create custom `TaskScheduler` that limits number of concurrently runninga tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use ThreadPool?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx

This provides system-aware throttling and has been around for a very long time

Comment: I don't even have access to this code base anymore, but if I did, I'd be thinking about the differences between tasks and threads- Threads are a low level API that ask the developer write code for things that are already done by the Task library https://stackoverflow.com/a/34449856/33264